# errbit clone in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, errbit

I'm looking for software similar to errbit but made in Node.JS. Ruby is a pain to install and maintain but I love how this software tracks errors and traces them.

The best thing is it's AirBrake.io compliant, so I can integrate with Slack or HipChat.

I would prefer some sort of app in Node.JS, but any other language will do as long as it's not Ruby as this app is.

I've searched up and down Google but not found anything that does what errbit does.

Let alone something that not only will track PHP using the AirBrake compliant PHP libraries:
https://github.com/flippa/errbit-php

But something that also tracks all JavaScript exceptions as errbit does so easily:

[image]

Not to mention GitLab integration as errbit does. Right now I would settle for the basic functionality of errbit without integrations as long as I could track PHP and JS automatically and manually sending events.

Answer (score 0):

I believe we build something that very close to what you looking for: https://github.com/sergeyksv/tinelic

Tinelic is Node.JS based application and its browser side error and performance monitoring module can be used separately from other features.